# Como evito el error demasiadas conexiones abiertas

Tags: c#, clase, método

Mi Dilema es que tengo un método de tipo MySqlDataReader que ejecuta una consulta que le envió por parámetro y me devuelve los datos... Para leer estos datos debo crear una Variable del mismo tipo de donde este llamando el Método, hasta ahí bien, Funciona pero al avanzar en el Proyecto el Servidor me bloquea debido a que excedo el numero de conexiones abiertas, pero si cierro la conexión en el método los datos no los puedo leer cuando invoco el método

Codigo:

La Varieble Conexion esta Declarada asi en mi Clase:

```
    //VARIABLE CONEXION (USADA EN LOS METODOS)
    private MySqlConnection Conexion;
```

Y el Metodo es este:

```
    public MySqlDataReader Consultar(String sql)
    {
        try
        {
            //INICIALIZAMOS UNA NUEVA CONEXION CON LOS PARAMETROS DEL CONSTRUCTOR
            Conexion = new MySqlConnection(StringConexion.ToString());

            //ABRIMOS LA CONEXION
            Conexion.Open();

            //SE CREA UN COMANDO CON EL SQL OBTENIDO POR PARAMETRO Y LA VARIABLE CONEXION
            MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, Conexion);

            //VARIABLE "Datos" QUE GUARDARA LOS DATOS DE LA BDD AL EJECUTAR EL COMANDO
            MySqlDataReader Datos = Comando.ExecuteReader();

            //RETORNAMOS LOS DATOS OBTENIDOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS
            return Datos;
        }
        catch (Exception evt)
        {
            //EN CASO DE ERROR EN LA EJECUCION SE CAPTURA Y SE IMPRIME EL MENSAJE
            MessageBox.Show("Error Consultando: " + evt.Message);

            //EN CASO DE ERROR EL RETORNO SERA NULO, NO RETORNA DATOS
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            //CERRAMOS LA CONEXION EN CASO DE ERROR
            //this.CerrarConex();
        }

    }
```

y para leer los datos devueltos debo hacer esto:

```
ClaseBDD Obj_Consulta = new ClaseBDD();
```

Y leo los datos así:

```
MySqlDataReader datos = Obj_Consulta.Consultar("SELECT * FROM USUARIOS LIMIT 1;");
if(datos.Read()){
    //carga de datos ejemplo
    TextBox1.Text = datos.GetString(1);
}
```

Si Cierro la conexion en el Metodo me da error porque no devuelve nada pero si la mantengo abierta funciona la carga de datos pero exedo al numero de conexiones porque tengo muchos formularios donde ocupo este metodo
Alguna Sugerencia como puedo optimizar el Metodo o como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Aca hay un problema grave de arquitectura.. los metodos consultar salvo que ya te devuelvan un datatable, reader o lo que sea, no son buena idea justamente por esto...

Comment: y Como podría solucionar esto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He agregado un poco de codigo a la tuya:

```
 public DataTable Consultar(String sql)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt;
        try
        {
            Conexion = new MySqlConnection(StringConexion.ToString());
            Conexion.Open();
            MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, Conexion);
            MySqlDataReader dr = Comando.ExecuteReader();

            dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dt.CreateDataReader();
            Conexion.Close();//Todo bien cierra conexion
        }
        catch (Exception evt)
        {
            dt = null;// Null
            MessageBox.Show("Error Consultando: " + evt.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Conexion.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)//la conexion aun esta abierto
            {
                Conexion.Close();
            }
        }
        return dt;// retornar
    }
```

Comment: Probé el código y me salta el siguiente error cuando trato de ver los datos : 
Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed;


Alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 1):

Cambie el tipo del método por un DataTable y logre solucionar mi problema.
Espero que a alguien mas le resulte útil esta información.

```
    public DataTable Consultar(String sql)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Conexion = new MySqlConnection(StringConexion.ToString()))
            {
                Conexion.Open();

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, Conexion);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                da.Fill(dt);

                return (dt);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception evt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: "+evt.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Conexion.Close();
        }
    }
```

y se usa asi:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable data = BDD.Consultar("select * from invcom where cod_com = 101");
            textBox1.Text = data.Rows[0].Field<string>("des_com");
            textBox2.Text = data.Rows[0].Field<string>("cod_com");

            //o vincular los datos
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM Clientes");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```